# Azure Ubuntu server 14.04 port access

Tags: server, cloud, azure

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 server in Azure cloud with static publick IP address.

And I can not open the desirable TCP or UDP port for my service there.

I dont see external network in networks list.

Nothing similar in the azure portal related to ports.

Any idea how to forward port or make it accessable from the interner?

Comment: What firewall are you using?

Comment: none. ufw is inactive.

Comment: OK, first off, you need a firewall.  I recommend `apf`.  `sudo apt-get install apf-firewall`

Comment: Try this guide: https://davidwinter.me/install-apf-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: but why? absence of firewall does not block any port... =|

Comment: What's your server's IP address?

Comment: @Daniel, and you need it for what?

Comment: To see if there are any ports open at all.

Comment: But you seem to have solved the problem yourself, so moot point.

Comment: I know there are opened ports ) TY for help! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It appears that Azure has its own firewall, called.... `Security zones`.

So to open a port one needs to go to `portal.azure.com`, open `Security zone` to which target VM is assigned. Then in Settings of that zone in `Inbound security ruless` configure port, which needs to be open and save the setting.

Answer (score 0):

To Open port in Azure Ubuntu VM, you have to use **NSG** ( **Network Security Group**) which is azure firewall.

Login into Azure Portal ( portal.azure.com)

Search for and select the **resource group** for the VM, choose **Add**, then search for and select **Network security group**.

Select Create.

The **Create network security group** window opens.

Enter a name for your **network security group**.

Select or create a **resource group**, then select a **location**.

Select Create to **create the network security group**.

***Create an inbound security rule***

Select your **new network security group**.

Select **Inbound security rules**, then select **Add**.

Choose a **common Service** from the **drop-down menu**, such as **HTTP**. You can also select Custom if you want to provide a specific port to use.

Optionally, change the Priority or Name. The priority affects the order in which rules are applied: the lower the numerical value, the earlier the rule is applied.

Select **Add** to create the rule.

Please refer the below URL which help you to Open port for Ubuntu VM.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal